# Rsync and ssh on android: No such file or directory

Tags: android, ssh, rsync

I'm trying to write an android app that backs up data from selected directory of an android device to a remote host using rsync and ssh. When I run the rsync command from adb shell as follows, it works:

```
rsync -rvz -e "/system/xbin/ssh -y -p 22" "/mnt/sdcard/" "rajeesh@10.0.2.2:backup/"
```

But my java code using Runtime.exec fails with an error that says:

```
Error: rsync: failed to exec /system/xbin/ssh -y -p 22: No such file or directory (2)
```

The code I used is as follows:

```
String[] commands = {
  "rsync", "-rvz", "-e", "\"/system/xbin/ssh -y -p 22\"",
  "\"/mnt/sdcard/\"", "\"rajeesh@10.0.2.2:backup/\""
};
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

Both rsync and ssh have been placed at /system/xbin and chmoded to 755. Tried replacing "rsync" with "/system/xbin/rsync" also but the issue remains. What would be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue myself.

When run directly from the shell, quotes have specific meaning and they are required here as follows:

```
rsync -rvz -e "ssh -y -p 22" "/path/to/src/" "/path/to/dest"
```

My java snippet above was trying to run the command with the quotes escaped, like "\"arg\"". But quotes not required when used outside shell. The correct usage is:

```
String[] commands = {
    "/system/xbin/rsync", "-rvz", "-e", "/system/xbin/ssh -y -p 22",
    "/mnt/sdcard", "rajeesh@10.0.2.2:backup/"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe problem is that the destination path (rajeesh@10.0.2.2:backup/) is not absolute?

Also if you what to sync your files in the same device, maybe you should try to not use ssh? And do something like that:

```
rsync -rvz /mnt/sdcard/some_directory /backup
```

Comment: No, first attempt was using absolute path. Same error. Not syncing with same device . It's between local machine & emulator and it's a test before connecting with another real remote server.

Comment: Error which you got is realy looks like there is no file ssh in your /system/xbin/ directory, but as you wrote it is in that place, and you don't get any permission errors. So unfoturnately i have not other variants.
What if you run  
`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rsync -rvz -e '/system/xbin/ssh -y -p 22' /mnt/sdcard/ rajeesh@10.0.2.2:/backup/")`